# Formatting datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have some rows in my dataset with the following release date format:

```
1995-10-30
```

It is an object/string. However, I want to convert it to datetime, so I wrote the following to achieve that:

```
movies_df["release_date"] = pd.to_datetime(movies_df.release_date)
```

It gets converted to datetime as it should, but I would like to have the following format

```
mm-dd-year
```

I have tried yearfirst=False and dayfirst=False but nothing seems to be happening and I cant figure out why it isnt working.

I have also tried to specify the format in the to_datetime method as following:

```
movies_df["release_date"] = pd.to_datetime(movies_df.release_date, format="%Y/%m/%d", dayfirst=False, yearfirst=False)
```

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 1):

You can convert datetimes to strings with format `mm-dd-YY`:

```
movies_df["release_date"] = pd.to_datetime(movies_df.release_date).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

But if want datetimes in format `mm-dd-YY` it is not possible in python.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to keep the datetime datatype to make comparisons on the dataset easier

Comment: @JokkeMedKniven - Unfortuantely it is not possible, datetimes are always in same format `YY-mm-dd`